# JS и _ в префиксе

Tags: javascript, классы, getter, underscore.js

Есть такой код:

```
class Ab{
  constructor(n){
    this.name = n;
  }

  get name(){return this._name }
  set name(value){ this._name = value }
}

console.log(new Ab(1).name);
```

Все работает. Вопрос такой. Если в сеттере или геттере перед названием метода/свойства поставить _ , то интерпритатор что сделает? То есть по факту такого свойства нету, но оно берет это свойство, но без _

Answer (score 1):

> Если в сеттере или геттере перед названием метода/свойства поставить _ , то интерпритатор что сделает?

Ничего не сделает.

В данном случае используется следующая особенность яваскрипта: создание поля при его отсутствии в момент присваивания.

Первый раз когда присваивается `this._name` в объекте создается соответствующее поле.

В итоге запись данного класса эквивалентна следующей:

```
class Ab{
  constructor(n){
    this._name = n;
  }

  get name(){return this._name }
  set name(value){ this._name = value }
}
```

Поведение никак не поменялось, однако теперь видно, что методы get и set просто используют существующее поле, которое инициализируется в конструкторе.

---

```js
class Ab {
  constructor(n) {
    this.name = n;
  }

  get name() {
    return this.$name
  }
  set name(value) {
    this.$name = value
  }
}

console.log(new Ab(1).name);

class Ab1 {
  constructor(n) {
    this.name = n;
  }

  get name() {
    return this.custom
  }
  set name(value) {
    this.custom = value
  }
}

console.log(new Ab1(2).name);
```

Comment: Етить я нифига не понял из этого объяснения. Дак я со своим ответом получаюсь прав или нет?

Comment: @Diskyp, Нет. не важно какое имя поля будет использоваться внутри свойства, важно то, что в конструкторе в момент присваивания оно создается и далее используется.

Comment: А свойством в данной ситуации вы что называете? Я тут могу отыскать только поле, методы: где один геттер, а другой сеттер, класс и конструктор.

Comment: @Diskyp, по аналогии с C# - совокупность `get`/`set`. Хотя с точки зрения js любое поле/метод - является свойством и можно получить его PropertyDescriptor

Comment: А "не важно какое имя поля", подразумевалось "неважно сколько нижних подчёркиваний"? Потомучто если ТС в геттере указал бы `this.$name`, например, то у него бы выдало undefined вместо единички. А если бы `this._n____a_m___e`, то ничего бы не изменилось.

Comment: @Diskyp, добавил в ответ сниппет

Comment: Ааа, просто в конструкторе выполняется установленный тут же в классе сеттер, вместо стандартного присваивания. Я только сейчас это осознал, внимательно всматриваясь. Ваше объяснение получается то же самое значило? От своей ереси я, конечно же, отрекаюсь.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80597/discussion-between-grundy-and-diskyp).